# When binding an fbo do you need to call glFramebufferTexture2D every frame?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es

On each draw frame when I bind an FBO am I supposed to call

```
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                ResourceManager.windowTex[0], 0);
```

Are you only supposed to call this when you initialize your framebuffer or every frame? It doesn't draw for me unless I call it after `glBindFramebuffer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attachment bindings are part of the FBO state. You only need to call `glFramebufferTexture2D()` once, while the FBO is bound. Those same textures will still be attached when you later bind the same FBO again.

One possible trap is that the texture object must have been created before it can be attached to an FBO. Generating the name alone is not enough, it needs to be bound at least once to create the actual texture object. For example, the following would be an **error**:

```
GLuint texId = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &texId);

GLuint fboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(...);
```

The texture object was not created in this case before being attached to the FBO. The following on the other hand is valid:

```
GLuint texId = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLuint fboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexImage2D(...);
```

Note that the texture does not have to be currently bound when `glFramebufferTexture2D()` is called, and it's also not necessary for texture data to have been specified at that point. It just needs to have been bound at least once to trigger creation of the texture object.

Comment: Are you missing a `glBindFramebuffer` call in your code? Can you edit to update with the required call?